# Safari input type email required

Tags: javascript, php, html, safari

I have a contact form in html/php, everything works fine however in SAFARI browser If I try to contact/submit without write in all input boxs the form don't validate

For example, I have

```
<form>
<input id="txtEmail" class="formincricao" type="email" required placeholder="email" value="" name="txtEmail"/>
<input type="submit" name="btnSendInfo" value="send" id="btnSendInfo" />
</form>
```

The required don't work Also the type email... in safari don't validate emails

I try to validate using

```
var forms = document.getElementsByTagName('form'); for (var i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {
forms[i].noValidate = true;

forms[i].addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
    //Prevent submission if checkValidity on the form returns false.
    if (!event.target.checkValidity()) {
        event.preventDefault();
        alert('Please, fill the form');
        //Implement you own means of displaying error messages to the user here.
    }bnbvds
}, false); }
```

However Still not working

Comment: Can you post your PHP, along with the rest of the form and any relevant Javascript?

Comment: yes, I can post php, and javascript. No problem

Answer (score 0):

The html5 'required' keyword doesn't play as well with safari as it does with, say, chrome. You should write your own javascript validation or use one of the many [prerolled validation libraries](http://ericleads.com/h5validate/).

Comment: Yes, I understand. And I try to create javascript validation. However I still can't validate emails

Comment: You can use javascript regular expressions to make sure that an @ symbol is present, or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type='text' id='txtEmail'/>
<input type='submit' name='submit' onclick='Javascript:checkEmail();'/>
```

Now when the button is clicked then the JavaScript function SubmitFunction() will be called. Now write the bellow code in this function.

```
<script language="javascript">

function checkEmail() {

    var email = document.getElementById('txtEmail');
    var filter = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;

    if (!filter.test(email.value)) {
    alert('Please provide a valid email address');
    email.focus;
    return false;
 }
}</script>
```

Now you have successfully validate your HTML controls through JavaScript.

Comment: Hi, Thanks. It's possible to use with form?

Comment: still sent form... in blank... without control email